# The same content but different output (it becomes landscape)

Tags: landscape, sumatrapdf

After a long nap on my computer, I found (surprisingly) that my main.pdf file got landscape. Further study on the reason why it became landscape totally confuse me.

This is what I found:

- If I rename the file and compile, I will get the desired direction (as is shown in main2.pdf).
- If I paste the code to a new file and compile, I will get the desired direction.
- If I change something in (main.tex) and compile it, the file remains landscape.
- I delete all files generated by the compiler, and then remake (main.tex). The file remains landscape.

My Tex code is: (the same for both file)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\begin{document}
Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant
\end{document}
```

My compiling rule is (under windows 18.03 -> WSL, the prefix "ubuntu.exe run" tells Windows to use WSL->Ubuntu to run the command.)

```
ubuntu.exe run latexmk -xelatex -logfilewarninglist -time -synctex=1 -file-line-error (MyFileName).tex
```

My XeTeX version:

```
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
```

Here are my files (screen shot)
[image: main.pdf (Why it's landscape?)]
[image: main2.pdf (Its direction is desired!)]

Comment: can you make the two pdf and the two log-files available?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It seems that I have solved it (with the help of the answer). So thank you! (and maybe I will not provide any more info like pdf-files and log-files). Anyway thanks to your suggesting and I will check their differences before I ask another question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using Sumatra to display your PDF file. You can rotate the displayed document in *Menu > View > Rotate...* or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> hotkeys. Sumatra will then remember the document orientation across sessions and reloads. This would be totally plausible after taking a nap on your computer's keyboard and it would explain all your symptoms.